# UIColor new property for iOS 13, such as label, secondaryLabel, tertiaryLabel and quaternaryLabel, what is use of this?

Tags: ios, uicolor, ios13

iOS 13 introduced some new property for UIColor class, such as label, secondaryLabel, tertiaryLabel and quaternaryLabel

what is the use of these properties? , how to use these properties?

```
/* Foreground colors for static text and related elements.
     */
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open class var label: UIColor { get }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open class var secondaryLabel: UIColor { get }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open class var tertiaryLabel: UIColor { get }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open class var quaternaryLabel: UIColor { get }
```

Comment: Please read [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface?language=objc)

Comment: Also see the [UI Element Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors) section of the UIColor documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **Semantic Colors**. That means the name of the color defines regardless of it's actual color. Instead, it's name by it's usage. This will help you to use color in dark mode and light mode and many other situations without being concerned about the contrast of the color.

Some colors (of the system) have four different variations:

- primary
- secondary
- tertiary
- quaternary

These are usually lighter and darker versions of the original color.

Some of theme have other variations like, **base** and **lifted** which are used for normal and modal presentations to prevent colors from mixing visually.

Watch [Implementing Dark Mode on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/) to learn more about it